# TripleDes CBC Nodejs implementation throuble

Tags: node.js, cryptography, 3des, cbc-mode

i need to replicate in Nodejs the results of the 3DS CBC encrypt in http://tripledes.online-domain-tools.com/.

This is my code:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const cipher = crypto.createCipher('des-ede3-cbc', key);
password = Buffer.from('MYPASS', 'utf8');

let encrypted = [cipher.update(password)];
encrypted.push(cipher.final());
encrypted = Buffer.concat(encryptedArr);
console.log(encrypted.toString('hex'));
```

The result of tripledes.online-domain-tools.com is:

[image: Note that the result should be 59 30 20 02 a5 8c dd 5e, but my code gives me 33 97 d8 b0 e3 00 d1 53]

Note that the result should be 59 30 20 02 a5 8c dd 5e, but my code gives me 33 97 d8 b0 e3 00 d1 53.

What am i missing?

*Edit2: 
Following your suggestions, I changed my code (Also added some Tests made with the guide of the NIST Publication):*

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
function encrypt (inputkey, keyformat, password, passwordformat) {
    let shortkey = Buffer.from(inputkey, keyformat);
    let key = Buffer.alloc(24);
    key.fill('\0');
    for (i = 0; i < shortkey.length; i++) {
        key[i] = shortkey[i];
    }
    let IV = Buffer.alloc(8);
    const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('des-ede3-cbc', key, IV);
    password = Buffer.from(password, passwordformat);

    let encryptedArr = [cipher.update(password)];
    encryptedArr.push(cipher.final());
    encrypted = Buffer.concat(encryptedArr);
    return encrypted;
}

console.log(encrypt('1046913489980131','hex','0000000000000000','hex')); // works 
console.log(encrypt('1007103489988020','hex','0000000000000000','hex')); // works
console.log(encrypt('10071034C8980120','hex','0000000000000000','hex')); // works
console.log(encrypt('1046103489988020','hex','0000000000000000','hex')); // works
console.log(encrypt('MYKEY','utf8','MYPASS','utf8')); // fails
```

Every `Permutation Operation Known Answer Test` of the NIST works great, but several other examples (including the one of the image) just fails

The reason i'm testing with this shady page is because my service provider is using it as reference.

Comment: The initialization vector might be guilty.

Comment: just my wild guess.. the webpage states that it prolongs the key to match the required key length and uses (part of) sha1  of the key as IV. your code doesn't do that

Comment: I overlooked that, i'm going to check it

Comment: @FrançoisP. With an IV of 0 `let IV = Buffer.alloc(16);`, the result is the same, it seems that crypto works with an IV of 0 if none is provided

Comment: Your are not using an IV in your example, you must use crypto.createCipheriv to pass an IV

Comment: Encryption does not happen with passwords, instead it happens with keys.  Triple DES is typically implemented with 2 keys of 56-bits each (112 bits total).  Find out what the online tool is doing with the "key" input to make it the right size.  Or better, try to make your implementation match the [NIST test vectors](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/SP/nistspecialpublication800-20.pdf) rather than matching this questionable online tool.

Comment: You're right @FrançoisP., I updated the question

Comment: As long as you don't know the exact key derivation used I'd simply ignore the difference between the online tool and your implementation. I once tried about 10 different variations on key derivation of one of these tools and I still failed. For all you know it simply extends the key with whatever is in the memory after the passphrase (as this is what OpenSSL and some other C libraries without memory protection do).

Comment: hi @AlexisRodríguez have you checked the solution  i gave you !!!

Comment: Hey guys sorry to enter in your subject, perhaps you can he[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62987347/invalid-key-length-error-using-createdecipheriv-from-crypto)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This site made me some troubles for some time ,  well here is the implementation it uses internally to expand the key to be a 24 bytes !
i am going to talk about tripledes but i guess this would apply to other  algorithms used by this site

**step 1**

it first checks if the key entered has the length that it expects it to be, (you can find a table at the bottom of that site telling the length of key for  each Encryption algorithm)
if it does not it will complete with `0x00` bytes like this:

```
var key;// is a string containing the bytes wich will be used to encrypt  the msg
var nullByte = 0x00;
var padding_needed;
for (var i=key.length ;i < expected_key_length ; ++) 
{padding_needed =padding_needed + nullBute.tostring(16);  }
key = key + padding_needed
```

so for example the length that it expects for 3DES is 24 bytes ; if you happen to enter just 15 bytes like this (112233445566778899aabbccddeeff) it will be like if you entered (112233445566778899aabbccddeeff00)

**step2**

in the case of tripledes the algorithm to expand the 16 bytes to 24 bytes key (which is the key length required by the algorithm) this site has a simple approach to do that 
it copies the first 8 bytes and append it to the end of the key like this

```
key =key + key.substring(0,8);
```

and that is the key that is going to be given to the 3DES encryption function to work with

this simple approache is not used by openssl for example , open ssl uses the first 8 bytes of the MD5 of the key ,and append them to the 16 bytes of the original key to get the 24 bytes key that is required by 3DES, like this

```
key = key + (MD5(key)).substring(0,8);
```

**Summary**

in that tool if you enter the key `112233445566778899AABBCCDDEEFF`  is the same as if you entered `112233445566778899AABBCCDDEEFF00` and same as if you entered `112233445566778899AABBCCDDEEFF001122334455667788` so to solve your problem you should give your function the complete 24 bytes of key that you gave to that site and you will surely get the same results, beacause nodejs is probably is doing the same thing as openssl does to expand the key(uses md5)

**PS**
if you are using  the cbc mode which is your case try to specify the IV to be 8 bytes of \x00 like this "0000000000000000"
the results will be the same !!

here is a working implementation of your code you can check it in the site

```
    const crypto = require('crypto');
function encrypt (inputkey, keyformat, password, passwordformat) {
    let shortkey = Buffer.from(inputkey, keyformat);
    let key = Buffer.alloc(24);
    key.fill('\0');
    for (i = 0; i < shortkey.length; i++) {
        key[i] = shortkey[i];
    }
    let IV = Buffer.alloc(8);


    var expansionStart = shortkey.length>16?shortkey.length:16;
    for (i=expansionStart;i<24;i++){
        key[i]=key[i-expansionStart];
    } 
    console.log(key);
    const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('des-ede3-cbc', key, IV);
    password = Buffer.from(password, passwordformat);

    let encryptedArr = [cipher.update(password)];
    encryptedArr.push(cipher.final());
    encrypted = Buffer.concat(encryptedArr);
    return encrypted;
    }
    var enc = encrypt("112233445566778899AABBCCDDEEFF","hex","password","utf8");
    console.log(enc);
```