# Invalid key length error using createDecipheriv from crypto

Tags: node.js, cryptojs, 3des, cbc-mode

I need to decrypt a data using de triple DES encoding with CBC mode. This code above is the unsussefuly last try. When the decipher will be created, i got the fallow error:

```
Error: Invalid key length
    at Decipheriv.createCipherBase (internal/crypto/cipher.js:103:19)
    at Decipheriv.createCipherWithIV (internal/crypto/cipher.js:121:20)
    at new Decipheriv (internal/crypto/cipher.js:262:22)
    at Object.createDecipheriv (crypto.js:127:10)
    at Object.decrypt3DES (/home/didimo/projetos/node_anna_server/src/utils/exeCrypto.ts:132:25)
    at /home/didimo/projetos/node_anna_server/src/controllers/annaController.ts:67:19
    at step (/home/didimo/projetos/node_anna_server/src/controller`enter code here`s/annaController.ts:33:23)
    at Object.next (/home/didimo/projetos/node_anna_server/src/controllers/annaController.ts:14:53)
    at /home/didimo/projetos/node_anna_server/src/controllers/annaController.ts:8:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
```

There is my code:

```
  var data = "XAWHNurb7eQRxbA/vuC09Q==";
  var iv = "O6VMaT2M9Pk=";
  var key = "UqOKIBu82BMiz4hEh+TqJpobsO9DonWo";

  var crypto = require("crypto");
  var alg = "des-ede-cbc";

  var keyBuffer64 = new Buffer(key, "base64");
  var keyBufferUtf8 = new Buffer(keyBuffer64.toString("utf8"), "utf8");

  var ivBuffer64 = new Buffer(iv, "base64");
  var ivBufferUtf8 = new Buffer(ivBuffer64.toString("utf8"), "utf8");

  var encryptedData = new Buffer(data, "base64");

  var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(alg, keyBufferUtf8, ivBufferUtf8);
  var decoded = decipher.update(encryptedData, "base64", "utf8");
  decoded += decipher.final("utf8");

  return decoded;
```

Answer (score 0):

After 3 days i discovered the answer by trial and error, was missing convert the iv and key values to hexadecimals. i hope this post helps somebody hehe.

```
  var data = "aNwsjalhzHnZc0UvMjt8CA==";
  var iv = "O6VMaT2M9Pk=";
  var key = "JajN48do5d/p5EMk2AsxUiedQd7eusdK";

  var ivBufferHex = Buffer.from(iv, "base64").toString("hex");
  var keyBufferHex = Buffer.from(key, "base64").toString("hex");

  var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(
    "des-ede3-cbc",
    Buffer.from(keyBufferHex, "hex"),
    Buffer.from(ivBufferHex, "hex")
  );
  decipher.setAutoPadding(true);
  var decryptedData = decipher.update(data, "base64", "utf8");
  decryptedData += decipher.final("utf8");

  return decryptedData;
```